# Bash is swallowing up C-h, C-j, C-k, and C-l

Tags: bash, ssh, terminal

I discovered this problem when trying to map C-h ... C-l to move between panes in Tmux. When I pressed the keys, nothing gets transmitted to Tmux.

This is on an Ubuntu 14.04 VM with Bash 4.3.11. I am sshing in from my Mac OS Mojave.

I am able to use these keys on my Mac. For example, when I type them into cat, it receives the keys and spits out some text:

```
  ~/mac: cat
^H^K^L
```

When I run cat over ssh on my VM, with a terminal explicitly allocated, it works as well:

```
  ~/mac: ssh -t vm "cat"
^H^K^L
```

But when I log into my VM and run cat, the characters get swallowed up instead of getting passed into cat:

```
  ~/vm: cat


# hitting C-h, C-k, C-l...nothing happens
```

As the experiment with `cat` indicates, it's not the terminal on my VM that's swallowing up the input. My understanding is that the input goes from terminal to bash to the process running inside bash, so that seems to  indicate that bash is the one swallowing the input. How can I debug this further?

Answer (score 0):

*Disclaimer: I would put this down as a comment but I don't have enough karma so please don't downvote me everyone.*

Bash uses GNU readline library to handle command-line editing and keybindings.

Can you post the output of this command so we can see if there is anything bound to "Control-hjkl" that would prevent the key sequence and from getting through:

```
bind -p | grep -v "(not bound)"
```